# How to find top 10 values in a xarray dataset with coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

i have used this syntax which helped in finding the maximum of the dataset and which coordinates they are at: da.where(da==da.max(), drop=True).squeeze()

is there a way like this to find the top 10 values/ 90th percentile of the dataset and which coordinates they are at?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to use the `.quantile()` functionality in xarray. This is in essence just a wrapper around the `.reduce()` method, for the case where you reduce the array using the `np.nanpercentile()` function.

For example in your case:

```
da.quantile([5, 95], dim='time', interpolation='linear')
```

Where because the question is a bit vague, I've assumed you're taking the quantile over the `time` dimension. The interpolation is something you can play about with, but if in doubt I use `linear` or `lower`.

For the second part of your question, if you're certain there aren't repeated values in your DataArray then you could just use the `.where()` method to find where the data matches these percentiles, otherwise I'm not sure if there's a simple way to do this?

Read more here:
http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.quantile.html

And for a bit of the development history:
https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/561

Cheers! :)

Comment: When I run this it takes a long time and then returns the entire array (instead of just the quantile). Also I think you want `[0.5, 0.95]` as your quantile instead of the integers